# Choosing which input to store where into an ArrayList? (Read from Scanner)

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read in a list of Integers from a scanner, using user input, and store all input into an ArrayList, except the last integer the user inputs, of which I want to store within an Integer, (Integer key;)  How can I do this?

I've tried putting it into a int[] first but I don't know how many integers the user will input.  Is there a way to directly read in all integers to the ArrayList excluding the last one, which would be stored within the Integer key?

What I have so far:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> theList;
private Integer theKey;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] integers = null;
    System.out.println("Enter a list of integers, the final being a key");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
       while (scanner.hasNext())
       {
         integers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
         i++;
       }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex)
    {
    }
    for (int k = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(integers[k] + " ");
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your code here. That is, in your question. And not on external pages.

Comment: To add to @Sufian's comment, welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). To indent your code when you **edit**, paste it into the html text box, highlight it and press ctrl-k.

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  So I guess you can just copy paste code into the text field and it can tell that it's code and not just regular writing?

Comment: @LogwanaMan No, the ctrl-k will indent it to the proper level (4 spaces) **to** be seen as code.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `List<Integer>`. Read all of the `int`s into it, and then (when there are no more `int`s), [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) the last one. Something like,

```
System.out.println("Enter a list of integers, the final being a key");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    al.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
int key = al.remove(al.size() - 1); // <-- the last one is removed, and returned.
```

Comment: Thank You, I think i just forgot that you can call a bunch of useful methods on Lists and such.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all numbers in list than assign last element to some variable and than remove the last element from the list.